# How to represent unique attribute in Z-notation without quantifiers?

Tags: formal-methods, z-notation

Full disclosure, this is for a university course. I don't expect an answer outright, but help would be appreciated.

I need to model an Item entity using Z-notation. This is the description:

> Item: Every item has a name and a unique ID which can be used to uniquely describe the item. An item also has a price (positive float) and a category.

Part of the requirement is modelling these entities **without** quantifiers.

This is what I ended up with, but I'm not sure that it's correct:

[Schema for Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuW11.png)

The idea being that the name is some combination of strings, the ID is a tuple of a positive integer and said name, and both the price and the category are mapped with total functions.

The first predicate is to ensure a positive price, the second is to ensure the uniqueness of the ID, i.e. reduce the domain to all integers that are not already assigned. **I don't think this is correct, though.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue with your approach is that you try to put information about the whole system (or part of it) into the description of a single item. E.g. you specified the price as a mapping from the id to a float - which is fine in principle - but you do not have such a function for each item.

There are many ways to specify this, I show two approaches:

1. You have two schemas: E.g. `Item` and `Database`

   ```
   +-- Item -----
   | id: ℕ
   | name: String
   | price: ℝ
   | category: String
   |----
   | price ≥ 0
   +----------

   +-- Database -----
   | items: ℕ +-> Item
   |----------
   ```

   This way you have the ID of each item moved from the item itself. When each item has also a field `id`, it would be complicated to state without quantifiers the fact that `items` should map an id to an item with the same id. Or when you just use a set of items it would be complicated to describe without quantifiers that two items must have distinct identifiers.

The uniqueness of the id for each item is guaranteed by `items` being a function.

2. Or just use several functions for each aspect of an item:

   ```
   +-- Items -----
   | ids: ℕ
   | name: ids --> String
   | price: ids --> ℝ
   | category: ids --> String
   +----------
   ```

   But stating the fact that all prices must be non-negative without quantifiers would be hard. Maybe by replacing `ℝ` by `{ x:ℝ | x≥0}`.

A general remark: Do you need compute with your IDs? Maybe you can introduce a type with `[ID]` instead. The same applies for the category (e.g. `[CATEGORY]`).

And is the name not just a single string? But I don't think it would be a set of (unordered) strings.